# MailJet-Email Template using conditional statement in BLOCKED ststus

Tags: node.js, mailjet, transactional-email

Used mailJet module in node js

// template

> ## Hello {{var:first_name:""}},
>
> Welcome to Mailjet. This is an example of a templating 
>         language message. This message contains variables and 
>         nested loops (for .. endfor)! You could also embed 
>         conditions (if .. else ..).
>
> http://www.mailjet.com"}}">
>         Here is a link to click!
>
>   {% for rock_band in var:rock_bands %}
> - Title: {{ rock_band.name }}
>
>     {% for member in rock_band.members %}
>   - Member name: {{ member }}
>     {% endfor %}
>   {% endfor %}

// data

> ```
>       {
>         "Subject": "test subject",
>         "MJ-TemplateID": "79501",
>         "MJ-TemplateLanguage": true,
>         "Recipients":[{ 'Email':"email here(valid email)"}],
>         "Vars": {
>           "first_name": "test name",
>           "rock_bands" : [{
>             "name": "test_name",
>             "members" : ['t','v']
>           }]
>         }
>       };
> ```

After successfully send email from node application,i checked MailJet dashboard but it's under **BLOCKED** status.
but template without conditional statements working fine.

Hope there's solution for it and thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1):

The messages appear with status "blocked" when there is an error in the template. I tested the for loop provided and it worked fine for me so most likely there is another issue in the template syntax. Enable the template error management to receive a report about the error:
https://dev.mailjet.com/guides/#templates-error-management

If you still face troubles finding the error, [contact Mailjet support](https://www.mailjet.com/support/ticket) as the issue would be related to the specific template.